# How to access a Vuejs data property from another data property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

These are my code

```
data: {
     cat1 : {name: "Category 1", reference : false},
     cat2 : {name: "Subcategory 2", reference: this.cat1}
}
```

When I am going to called this.cat2.reference from any function, its giving me value false. I don't want to declare the cat1 outside somewhere and make reference here. I want the exactly same structure as above so that, I can get the cat2 reference perfectly.

Anyone could you please advice me any solution?

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to create your `data` object with some [getter methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

For example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#newUser',
  data: () => { // make sure to use a "data" function
    // initialise with a declared variable
    const formData = {
      cat1, // not sure where these come from
      cat2,
      cat3,
      cat5: { name: 'Subcategory 5', get reference() { return formData.cat1 }}
    }
    return { formData }
  }
}
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/ztfgapxh/

Comment: Not worked for me. Please view this video https://streamable.com/kw9wa9 and give me a possible solution.
This was my entire code and applied for cat5. 

 new Vue({
       el: "#newUser",
       data: {
           formData: {
               cat1, cat2, cat3,
               cat5: {
                   get reference() {
                       return formData.cat1
                   }
               },
           },
       },
   });

Comment: @ShamimSdr I think you need to take a closer look at my answer, especially the bit that says _"make sure to use a data function"_

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll be better using a computed property:

```
data: {
  cat1 : {name: "Category 1", reference : false}
}
computed: {
  cat2() {
    return {name: "Subcategory 2", reference: this.cat1}
  }
}
```

Now you can call `this.cat1` and `this.cat2` but cat2 will be updated every time cat1 changes.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

EDIT: if you want to handle all `catX` in a consistent way, you can have all of them to be computed properties

Comment: It works but I want to make the reference from data property not from outside somewhere. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to have that on the data declaration and not as a computed property? I don't know how to do what you ask, but I don't understand why you want that specifically

Answer (score 0):

You can set the reference as a function that will return this.data.cat1 :

```
data: {
     cat1 : {name: "Category 1", reference : ()=> {return null;}},
     cat2 : {name: "Subcategory 2", reference: ()=> {return this.data.cat1;}}
}
```

In order to get the reference of the cat2 you'll need to call it as a function :

```
var referenceOfCat2 = this.data.cat2.reference();
//referenceOfCat2 = {name: "Category 1", reference : ()=> {return null}}
```

Although if you try to call this function outside the component itself, it won't work. If you want to pass cat2 to another component, you'll need to set his reference (call the ref function ) before passing it, otherwise once it reaches the other component, the data target won't be the same (unless some tweaks) and the reference() won't work

Comment: not working to call cat1 reference as function. Getting this output  "reference:ƒ reference()" for value of this.cat2.reference

Comment: don't forget the () after reference, since its a function -- it works fine for me, I get {name: "Category 1", reference : ()=> {return null;}} when calling this.data.cat2.reference()